# Wrong splashscreen | Windows phone | Cordova

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, splash-screen

I've a problem with the splashscreen in Windows Phone with cordova. 
I'can't using  `ionic cordova resources`  because is not working. 
I have to set the images in Visual Studio and this is the problem : 
Visual Studio want (for example) a 2480 x 1200 (px) image and this is for desktop. Can I make the splashscreen for Mobile App? 
Here the screen:

[image: Visual Studio only want these resolutions]